# What is the best way to create a new column based on two conditions?

Tags: r

I have 60 years of daily weather data and want to label each winter (i.e. 1-60). Because winter's cross years, there's no way to subset or write a simple `ifelse` statement using just the months. A nested `ifelse` statement specifying both month and year for each of the 60 years seems impractical, is there a better way to do this?

Here is just an example with three years.

```
month<-c(11,12,1,2,3,4,11,12,1,2,3,4,11,12,1,2,3,4)
year<-c(1950,1950,1951,1951,1951,1951,1951,1951,1952,1952,1952,1952,1952,1952,1953,1953,1953,1953)
df<-cbind(month,year)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

I want the dates between Nov. 1950 and April 1951 to all be labeled 1 in a new column. The dates between Nov. 1951 - April 1952 labeled 2, etc.

I would like the final dataframe to look something like this:

```
    month year winter
1     11 1950      1
2     12 1950      1
3      1 1951      1
4      2 1951      1
5      3 1951      1
6      4 1951      1
7     11 1951      2
8     12 1951      2
9      1 1952      2
10     2 1952      2
11     3 1952      2
12     4 1952      2
13    11 1952      3
14    12 1952      3
15     1 1953      3
16     2 1953      3
17     3 1953      3
18     4 1953      3
```

Any thoughts on a simple way to do this, as I have 60 years of daily data for over 30 weather stations?

Comment: How about `df$winter = df$year + ifelse(df$month <= 4, -1, 0) - 1949` ?

Comment: Thanks @Jon Spring , this is a neat code that works on my data!

Comment: Or a little shorter: `df$winter = df$year + ifelse(df$month <= 4, -1950, -1949)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `cumsum` like this:

```
transform(df, winter = cumsum(month == 11))
```

giving:

```
   month year winter
1     11 1950      1
2     12 1950      1
3      1 1951      1
4      2 1951      1
5      3 1951      1
6      4 1951      1
7     11 1951      2
8     12 1951      2
9      1 1952      2
10     2 1952      2
11     3 1952      2
12     4 1952      2
13    11 1952      3
14    12 1952      3
15     1 1953      3
16     2 1953      3
17     3 1953      3
18     4 1953      3
```

Comment: Thanks! This works on the above example, however, my data is daily and the cumsum function therefore goes all the way up to 30 after the first year.